# How can I make an interpreter which reads an instruction set and assigns variables?

Tags: java, variables, interpreter

I'm writing an interpreter program in Java which takes a string which represents an instruction set to assign variables and returns the variable displayed on the last line. So

```
A = 2
B = 4
C = A + B
C
```

when fed into the code, it should return 6, which is the value of C. I have the following code so far:

```
public class Interpreter2 {

public static int Scanner() {
    int returnStatement = 0;
    //Input instruction set in the quotation marks below
    String input = "A = 2\n B = 8\n C = A + B\n C";
    String[] lines = input.split("\n");
    for (String i : lines) {
        i = i.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        if (i.contains("=")) {
            String[] sides = i.split("=");
            String leftHand = sides[0];
            String rightHand = sides[1];
            int a = Integer.parseInt(leftHand);

            if (rightHand.contains("+")) {
                String[] add = rightHand.split("+");
                String num1 = add[0];
                String num2 = add[1];
                int num3 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                int num4 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                int sum = num3 + num4;
                a = sum;

            }else {
                int b = Integer.parseInt(rightHand);
                a += b;
                return a;
            }
        }else {
            returnStatement = Integer.parseInt(i);
            return returnStatement;
        }

    }
    return returnStatement;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Scanner());
    }
}
```

Currently however this returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
```

Which means that if there is a letter in the instruction set, it will not work. If `int a` is simply assigned as 0, the code returns `2`. 
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: When you parse `A=2`, you take LHS and RHS in a split. But then you try to `parseInt` on LHS, which would be `A`, which is not an integer.

Comment: Before you begin coding a solution to this problem, you should spend some time defining your problem domain (i.e. state the rules, assumptions, and constraints for your interpreter; determine its grammar and syntax). Then, you should develop a corresponding object model.  As it stands, your solution is procedurally written and does not benefit from any sort of object oriented abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Here

> int a = Integer.parseInt(leftHand);

you have getting a value "A" so you won't be able to parse it to integer.